# Comparing only the first elements of two differing arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays

When I run this, the if statement is *supposed* to compare only the first element of both arrays.  It works fine as long as array "ans" only contains y or Y, but if I enter a "yes", etc, it comes back false and shoots down to else.

```
    char y[2]= "y";
    char n[2] = "n";
    char ans[5];

    printf("Answer yes of no. (y/n) ");
    scanf(" %s", ans);
    if (strcasecmp(&ans[0], &y[0]) == 0)
    {
        printf("You said yes.\n");
        printf("%c, %s\n", y[0], ans);
    }
    else if (strcasecmp(&ans[0], &n[0]) == 0)
    {
        printf("You said no.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("hmm?\n");
    }
```

Comment: What language? C++ or C?

Answer (score 2):

Not really, `strcasecmp()` compares two strings, not two characters, even if you pass it the pointer to their first characters, it still compare two strings that start from this character  until a terminating `'\0'`.

You can compare their first characters ignoring case like this:

```
if (toupper(ans[0]) == toupper(y[0])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strncasecmp` instead of `strcasecmp`, so that you can compare just the first character rather than the entire string. Change:

```
if (strcasecmp(&ans[0], &y[0]) == 0)
```

to:

```
if (strncasecmp(ans, y, 1) == 0)
```

and similarly for the rest.